# Django - Custom Form Field Example

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a project in which I need to add a custom form field to a form (or formset) in which depending on the choice in the custom field selected, an integer in a database field is changed.

I can't seem to find any examples or prior questions which imply how to modify a database field via a custom field. I suspect it is done by overwriting the save() function in a ModelForm but cannot work out how.

Any advice on solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

An Example:

My class has an integer field which is the field that needs updating.

```
class Employee(Model):
    years = models.IntegerField()
```

However this field cannot be updated as it is, instead what is needed is a ChoiceField (I think) with different options that, depending on the selection, changes the field with a +1, -1, or reset to zero.

As previously mentioned this is where I imagine some work with the save() function needs to be done but am unsure.

As a side note in case this affects what can be done, eventually this ModelForm will need to be used in a formset so I can edit multiple objects on one page.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of what you're trying to do? That might help people help you more easily.

Comment: Added an example and some clarification, hope this helps.